# Angular build error on Azure DevOps with powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, angular7, azure-pipelines

I prepared a powershell script in azure devops build pipeline to create an artifact, but when I start build queue, I get an error which is below.

> The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

Can someone help me please.

**Powershell script:**

```
npm install

npm install -g typescript

npm install -g @angular/cli

ng build --configuration=production
```

**This is all the result of powershell script:**

```
##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Windows, macOS, or Linux.
Version      : 2.148.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'd:\a\_temp\90129c3e-4840-41d7-895c-2f9c8f6e5968.ps1'"
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\package.json'
npm WARN s No description
npm WARN s No repository field.
npm WARN s No README data
npm WARN s No license field.

up to date in 5.231s
found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\npm\prefix\tsc -> C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\npm\prefix\tsserver -> C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
+ typescript@3.4.5
updated 1 package in 2.063s
C:\npm\prefix\ng -> C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.3.9
added 295 packages from 180 contributors in 88.373s
The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

Comment: before the `ng build` add `cd path/to/angular/project`

Comment: Can you please confirm that your repository is getting cloned during build process ?

A common build logs of angular cli project :

1)  Prepare job   
2)  Initialize job   
3)  Checkout    
4)  Use Node 10.15.3  
5)  npm install packages  
6)  npm build

Comment: The problem was file path of Angular project like Shayki Abramczyk said, who comments to my question. 
When I push my branch to Azure Devops, 
They create a directory with the name of the project but I thought that Powershell script would work in angular project, however I was wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: @sapfile Great! I also added it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error said, you try to run `ng build` not in the project folder.

You need to run `cd path/to/project-folder` before.

Another option, in the Azure DevOps PowerShell task there is a option to specify "Working Directory" so enter there the project path.